# How to encode time embeddings in a diffusion model for 1D vectors?

Tags: generative-model, markov-property

For a project I'm working on, I'd like to try a diffusion model like illustrated in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.11239.pdf) by Ho et Al to generate 1D vectors. What I'm trying to figure out at the moment, is what kind of architecture should I use for the 1D case, given that those people use a U-net-based model including different layers like attention, residual, group norm, etc. The only requirement that such a model should satisfy is that **the input and output shapes should be the same**, as we're interested in predicting the **noise** associated with a particular timestep.

$$\mathcal{L}(\theta) := \mathbb{E}_{\textbf{x}_0, \, t, \, \varepsilon}\left[\|\varepsilon - \varepsilon_\theta(\sqrt{\bar{\alpha}_t}\textbf{x}_0 +\sqrt{1-\bar{\alpha}_t}\varepsilon,t)\|^2\right]$$

So for now, I'm considering a simple *autoencoder* architecture but I'm not sure **how and where** I should inject knowledge of timesteps using some sort of positional encoder as proposed in the paper by Ho et Al.

Additionally, I'm not even sure about they inject such knowledge into the model? Do they sum the obtained time embeddings over channels? Or over image dimensions?

Comment: 1D diffusion is already supported. See https://github.com/lucidrains/denoising-diffusion-pytorch/issues/116